# Why is dynamic not making the assumption that it can support this operation?

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have a class like this:

```
public sealed class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
    where T : RepositoryEntryBase, IRepositoryEntry, new() 
{
    /*Insert Stuff Here*/
}
```

I am trying to instantiate this class like so:

```
Repository<dynamic> v = new Repository<dynamic>();
```

and I'm getting an error like this:

> The type 'dynamic' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'ServiceLibraries.Repositories.Repository'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'dynamic' to 'Data.IRepositoryEntry'.

The MSDN documentation says the following, though:

> At compile time, an element that is typed as dynamic is assumed to support any operation.

Is there something I'm missing? Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Comment: How is "IRepository<T>" defined (where T: ...?)

Comment: public interface IRepository<T> where T : IRepositoryEntry, new()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider *non-dynamic* code within `Repository<T>`. It could have:

```
IRepositoryEntry entry = new T();
```

That's perfectly valid code - but isn't going to work with `T=dynamic`.

You can perform any operation on a value of type `dynamic`, but that doesn't mean you can use `dynamic` in every situation - and generics are precisely an example of where that just doesn't work.

It's important that the "dynamic-ness" *only* affects the code which knows (at compile-time) that it's using `dynamic`... so that *doesn't* include the `Repository<T>` code here, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the error, `Repository<T>` requires that `T` implement `IRepositoryEntry`.  However, `dynamic` cannot prove that it does implement that interface.

As far as generics go, `dynamic` is synonymous with `object`, and you couldn't use `Object` for type `T` either.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using 'T' in your class definition you are referring to a generic type (not necessarily a dynamic type).  Also your class definition enforces that the type that inherits from your Repository must also inherit from RepositoryEntryBase and implement IRepositoryEntry.  A dynamic type does not fulfill that contract